# Accept TestFlight invite with email address different to Apple ID?

Tags: app-store-connect, testflight

I want to to invite a few inside Testers to test the first build. Now these are work email addresses which may or may not be also their Apple IDs but i think its more likely that they receive the mail on their iPhone but use a private email in their Apple Accounts.

How would that work? Can they open the invite on their phones and then log in with different credentials to accept? Or are they asked to create a new Apple ID with the email address from the invite? And would this conflict with the Apple ID they are already signed into on their phones?

I just want to make it as convinient as possible for them and would also like to avoid asking them to pass around their private email.

Answer (score 4):

The email address which you register in Appstore Connect are consumed to send invitation code to the users(which in this case can be work email address).

The user could be using different Apple ID on his mobile , but he can open Testflight and there would be an option called redeem. once he clicks on it he can enter the code which is part of the invite on the company mail id and can get the app and test it.

Next updates to the app would be rolled out automatically once you allow it for internal testing.Above task would be a one time action needed.

This way you can enjoy best of both worlds and the end users can be comfortable as well.